# How to calculate specific column sum by using jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I know many people ask similar things before but I have try all the method and I still cannot get the sum for the specific column. I want to calculate and show the sum for the column debit and credit and total amount once i click on the page. Anyone can help me see am I using the wrong method to do the calculation. [JS.Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c1j7ubg8/4/)

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Debit</th>
      <th>Credit</th>
      <th>Document No</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="acc_table">
    <tr class="acc-row">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Testing 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>320</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Testing 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>250</td>
      <td>Testing 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
   <tr>
     <td>Total</td>
     <td><input type='text' id='totalDr' value='0.00' disabled></td>
     <td><input type='text' id='totalCr' value='0.00' disabled></td>
   </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<br><br>
<input type='text' id='totalAmount' value='0.00' disabled> //Total_dr + total_cr

<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var total_cr = 0;
          var total_dr = 0;
          $('table .acc_table .acc-row').each(function() {
            var $tr = $(this);
            var $column = $tr.find('td');
            var $debit = parseInt($column.next('td').html());
            var $credit = parseInt($column.next('td').next('td').html());
            if (!isNaN(value)) {
              total_dr += $debit; 
              total_cr += $credit;
            }
            var TotalAmount = (total_dr + total_cr) || 0; 
          });
          $("#totalDr").val(total_dr.toFixed(2)); //it should prompt 420
          $("#totalCr").val(total_cr.toFixed(2)); // it should prompt 350
          $("#totalAmount").val(TotalAmount.toFixed(2)) //it should prompt 770
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get td for debit and credit column using `td:eq(1)` and `td:eq(2)` and using same check if the value is not empty then add total to your required inputs.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var total_cr = 0;
  var total_dr = 0;
  var TotalAmount = 0;
  $('table .acc_table tr').each(function() {
    var $tr = $(this);
    //get td `1` debit 
    var $debit = $tr.find('td:eq(1)').text().trim() != "" ? parseInt($tr.find('td:eq(1)').text().trim()) : 0;
    //get td `2` credit side
    var $credit = $tr.find('td:eq(2)').text().trim() != "" ? parseInt($tr.find('td:eq(2)').text().trim()) : 0;
    total_dr += $debit;
    total_cr += $credit;

  });
  TotalAmount = (total_dr + total_cr) || 0; //put this out
  $("#totalDr").val(total_dr.toFixed(2));
  $("#totalCr").val(total_cr.toFixed(2));
  $("#totalAmount").val(TotalAmount.toFixed(2))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Debit</th>
      <th>Credit</th>
      <th>Document No</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="acc_table">
    <tr class="acc-row">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Testing 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>320</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Testing 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>250</td>
      <td>Testing 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type='text' id='totalDr' value='0.00' disabled></td>
      <td><input type='text' id='totalCr' value='0.00' disabled></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<br><br>


<input type='text' id='totalAmount' value='0.00' disabled> //Total_dr + total_cr
```

Comment: But actually my data is come from database so it is dynamic, so how can I make the :eq() to detect the tr itself??

Comment: Hi, `eq` just find td in your table structure so according to your html first column is `no` second is `debit` an so on you just need to change value of `eq` if the td for debit column is not at `1` position change it according to your original table column because index start from `0`  and do same for credit column as well.

Comment: or if you can give some class to credit and debit tds i.e : `<td class="debit">12</td>` then just change `td:eq(0)` to `.debit` and same for other as well.

Comment: Great, the second suggestion make me more easily to understand and I success to make it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I edit your code, it was 90% right but needed some fix

1. declare a TotalAmount variable outside `each method`
2. change this condition `if (!isNaN(value))` to `if (!isNaN($debit) || !isNane($credit))`
3. give `acc_table class` to all `<tr>` tag In `<tbody>` tag too loop through it and sum all values

============= JS ==========

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var TotalAmount = 0;
      var total_cr = 0;
      var total_dr = 0;
      $('table .acc_table .acc-row').each(function() {
        var $tr = $(this);
        var $column = $tr.find('td');
        var $debit = parseInt($column.next('td').html());
        var $credit = parseInt($column.next('td').next('td').html());
        console.log($debit);
        if (!isNaN($debit) || !isNane($credit)) {
          total_dr += $debit;
          total_cr += $credit;
        }
        TotalAmount = (total_dr + total_cr) || 0; 
      });
      console.log(TotalAmount)
      $("#totalDr").val(total_dr.toFixed(2));
      $("#totalCr").val(total_cr.toFixed(2));
      $("#totalAmount").val(TotalAmount.toFixed(2))
    });
```